# Terraform: Delete resource before creating another resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

**OVERVIEW**

I'd like to create a Route53 DNS record.  Depending on a variable it will either be a CNAME record or an ALIAS record.

On the first run, this works OK because neither of the records exists.

However, when updating the variable `var.route_53_redirection_type` to change the record type the `terraform apply` fails because it attempts to create the new record before the old one is deleted.

```
Error: [ERR]: Error building changeset: InvalidChangeBatch: [RRSet of type A with DNS name redirect is not permitted because a conflicting RRSet of type CNAME with the same DNS name already exists in zone.]
```

When `terraform apply` is run again it works because the record had been deleted on the previous run.

Here is the code:

```
resource "aws_route53_record" "alias" {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
  count = var.route_53_redirection_type == "ALIAS" ? 1 : 0
  zone_id = data.aws_route53_zone.public.zone_id
  name    = "redirect"
  type    = "A"
  alias {
    name                   = module.alb.alb_dns_name
    zone_id                = module.alb.alb_zone_id
    evaluate_target_health = true
  }
  
}

resource "aws_route53_record" "cname" {
  count = var.route_53_redirection_type == "CNAME" ? 1 : 0
  zone_id = data.aws_route53_zone.public.zone_id
  name    = "redirect"
  type    = "CNAME"
  ttl     = "5"
  records        = ["www.google.com"]
}
```

**QUESTIONS**

- Is it possible to ensure the deletion happens before the creation?
- Is there a better approach entirely, which removes the dependency?

**NOTES**
I've looked at [lifecycle](https://www.terraform.io/language/meta-arguments/lifecycle) and [depends_on](https://www.terraform.io/language/meta-arguments/depends_on) but neither of these seem applicable in this case.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you want to change the record type? What is the use case?

Comment: Thanks.  It's not something that will change very often.  In the short-term CNAME, long-term ALIAS.  The answer from @simmyk will probably do the trick.  It seems like a simple use case that I thought Terraform would be able to handle.

Comment: But otherwise no: you cannot specify order of deletion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it would be really hard to achieve what you want based on the requirements. I think that a better way of approaching this would be using `dynamic` block [1] and `for_each` [2] (still not sure that would work as expected). The code would then look like:

```
resource "aws_route53_record" "record" {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
  zone_id = data.aws_route53_zone.public.zone_id
  name    = "redirect"
  type    = var.route_53_redirection_type == "ALIAS" ? "A" : "CNAME"
  ttl     = var.route_53_redirection_type == "ALIAS" ? null : 5

  dynamic "alias" {
    for_each = var.route_53_redirection_type == "ALIAS" ? [1] : []
    content {
      name                   = module.alb.alb_dns_name
      zone_id                = module.alb.alb_zone_id
      evaluate_target_health = true
    }
  }

}
```

---

[1] https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/dynamic-blocks

[2] https://www.terraform.io/language/meta-arguments/for_each

Answer (score 0):

Any specific reason for updating the record type?

But if this is requirement of deleting any specific resource, we can always use destroy as destroy command can be used to destroy a complete set of cloud infrastructure or a targeted resource.

```
 terraform destroy --target aws_route53_record.cname
```

Comment: Thanks, see the comment above.  Yes, I appreciate this suggestion and it will work but it will require 2 runs and potential downtime while records are updated.